# Sequent calculus using prooftree

Tags: logic, proof-package

I am trying to write sequent calculus proofs using the `prooftree` package like the one on page 58 of [this document](http://www.ling.cam.ac.uk/Copil/papers/8-Gotham.pdf).

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is `prooftree` anyway? It is not a standard package (not on CTAN). Why do you particularly want to use that package? I see from comments what you don't want to use, but you don't say *which* package `bussproofs` is incompatible with, so nobody except you really knows what you are asking. In general, asking to construct a logical proof of type A with arbitrary proof package B is not a good strategy because, most often, it really cannot be done. Typically, such packages serve very specific needs: they are for proofs *in system X* or, at most, system X or Y.

Comment: Also, *which* proof on page 58?

Comment: OK. It is on CTAN but searching doesn't find it, for some reason.

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/proofs/taylor). I don't see any principled reason why you couldn't create the proof you need with this package. What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use the much better bussproofs.sty, not prooftree.sty.

Check out [this page at Latex for Logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/) for a mini-illustration, a link to the package and to the short-but-useful Latex for Logicians documentation. Bussproofs is easy, and produces excellent output.

Comment: I cannot, since it has the same latex syntax as another proof programme I am using to write some particularly complex proofs in that someone else gave me. I'd have to rewrite those proofs in bussproofs, and am not sure I would know how to...